# Questions Array into a file

Tags: java, arrays, file

I created a program that asks the user 10 random multiple choice questions. I also created a question class that feeds into my main method. I have an array for my 10 multiple choice questions and I need to take those questions and store them in a text file. The file needs to be formatted as such:
Question Text
Answer Option A
Answer Option B
Answer Option C
Answer Option D
Correct Answer

My question class has a constructor that is suppose correspond to the text file I need to create.

I am unsure how to start this and hoping to get some ideas that could help me.

Example of my code:

```
//Set question and answers.
            questions[0] = new P3A2_Harvey_4251833_Question("JVM stands for what?", "D");
            questions[0].setChoice("A. Java Variable Machine");
            questions[0].setChoice("B. Java Variable Method");
            questions[0].setChoice("C. Java Virtual Method");
            questions[0].setChoice("D. Java Virtual Machine");
            questions[1] = new P3A2_Harvey_4251833_Question("Every complete programming statement ends with what?", "A");
            questions[1].setChoice("A. Semicolon");
            questions[1].setChoice("B. Period");
            questions[1].setChoice("C. Colon");
            questions[1].setChoice("D. Question Mark");
            questions[2] = new P3A2_Harvey_4251833_Question("This type of expression can be either true or false", "C");
            questions[2].setChoice("A. Null Expression");
            questions[2].setChoice("B. Binary Expression");
            questions[2].setChoice("C. Boolean Expression");
            questions[2].setChoice("D. Method Expressions");
            for(int i = 0; i<questions.length;i++)
            {
                //Randomizing the questions in the array. 
                int n = rand.nextInt(3);
                System.out.print("Question " + (n+1)+":");
                System.out.println(questions[n].getQuestion());
                System.out.println(questions[n].getChoice());
                System.out.print("Enter your answer: "); 
                userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
                //Asking for users input reference to the question. 
                while(!userInput.equals("A")&&!userInput.equals("B")&&!userInput.equals("C")&&!userInput.equals("D"))
                {
                    System.out.println("invalid response");
                    System.out.print("Enter your answer: ");
                    userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: I am guessing you have the answers saved in another array or some list. All you have to do is to, loop through your array questions and along with the answer and write them to the file, on the basis of the fact that order and count of both answers and questions are same. I don't think, there'd be any problem in implementing this.

Comment: I added some of my code to the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close to your solution. Here is a suggestion.

As you have successfully created a `Question` class, you could write *an extra method for this class* which will be in charge of writing the question's contents to the given file. Something like that:

```
public class Question {
    //...

    public void write (PrintWriter out) {
        //TODO write your desired output
        out.println("This line will be written to whatever is given as parameter");
    }
}
```

*Then in your main,* you could create a file and have each question written to it. For instance, if you have a single question `q`, this would write to file named `filename.txt` :

```
Question q = new Question(...);

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("filename.txt");

q.write(writer); //Give the PrintWriter to the write method of Question class

writer.close();
```

I think you can figure out how to proceed from there on your own ;-).